# C++ Valid for indie 2d games?

Tags: c++, 2d

I am not currently developing any games, but am taking a C++ course. Will I actually be able to make any games with the knowledge I have from this course? I really just want to make a game with turrents and units with veterancy, nothing too advanced. But when I search c++ games online, it is nothing compared to the wealth of tutorials etc. provided for actionscript and other languages. thanks.

Comment: just develop a game in any language you like or you are mostly skilled in. besides number of libraries in c++ is by far the most! so when you find nothing it means you didn't search well.

Comment: Yes it's "valid", lots of 2D games have been made with C++.  But without knowing the specifics of what the course teaches you it's impossible to say whether or not you can make the specific games you want.  More than likely it won't teach you what you need to know with regards to graphics API more so than the language itself.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can make simple games using C++. That's the main language used by game developers; for just one place to start (there are tons, possibly on this site) look at [SDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_DirectMedia_Layer).

Comment: yah... there werent any tutorials on youtube. Idk. Its just a scientific programming class. Will it be easy enough for my to teach myself the API stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Start with SDL for graphics. Its not the simplest API on earth, but its not that bade and its reasonably powerful (though 2D). And there are lots of tutorials (such as the LazyFoo ones) to get you there. Don't even consider 3D without experience under your belt.

Then, work at emulating a couple of really old arcade games. Start with Pong. Work your way up to Space Invaders and so on.

I'm sorry - I lack any good resources to tell you how to actually code your games in C++. But, as an API, SDL should get you a good step of the (learning) way.